# Git - how to get a new file from a future commit when rolling back

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a git branch which has a normal Git commit history on it; there are additions/modifications/deletions throughout the development cycle.

I would like to rollback to a previous commit, but keep a file from the present commit, which is not in the commit I am rolling back to (or to flip it on its head, checkout a file from a future commit that is not present in the current commit).

E.g.:

```
--------A--------B--------- ...
                 + myFile.txt;

 $ git checkout #A
```

I would like to checkout commit #A, but retain `myFile.txt` which was added in commit `#B`.

Comment: I would checkout A, copy the file(s) I wanted to maintain to another place, rollback to B, then put the file(s) back.

Comment: Thanks! Other way around though ;) A was committed before B and I'd be rolling back to A :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use git checkout to do this, it takes a path as an optional argument:

`git checkout <commit> <path>`

Say you are currently at a commit with hash B and you want to reset all of your file except for goodFile.txt with their state from commit A.

`git checkout A` checkout the commit you want to get most of your files from

`git checkout B goodFile.txt` now checkout the specific good file from commit B

`git commit goodFile.txt` to commit it.

you'll now have a new commit with A as it's parent that has all the files from A and goodFile.txt from B

Comment: You need to separate the named commit and filepath with "--" when you do a checkout and do not forget to run  `git add goodFile.txt` before the commit

Comment: @joran As best as I can tell you don't need "--", it works for me without it.  Can you explain when you need the "--" and when you don't?

Comment: Also, `git checkout goodFile.txt` seems to stage the checked out files automatically.

Comment: you're right, index is updated before the working tree, one don't need to stage the file and one don't need to use "--" in this case. If you have named tree-ish with same name as a  filepath you need to use "--" to checkout the file and not the named tree-ish. One learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file myFile.txt somewhere out of the git repo, and then checkout A. Copy the File back inside the repo.

Answer (score 0):

Note your current commit SHA. You can use [`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) to get the file's state at that SHA and reproduce it after you roll back.

```
git show abcd1234:path/to/file > path/to/file
```

This is handy to look at any file in any commit-ish at any time, and works in the case of rollback because Git doesn't garbage collect that commit for a while, even though it's no longer on any of your branches. You have at least until it falls out of your reflog, which I believe Git holds onto for 30 days by default.

Answer (score 0):

While there are ways to get a single file that you wanted to maintain while rolling back, one could easily imagine much more complicated scenarios that would quickly get unwieldy.

The main question here is whether A is a new branch that you'll be creating (as a modified version of B). If it is, then you don't have to worry about "rewriting history" (since everything will be new), and there's a very pleasant option to manage this and much more complicated scenarios: git rebase.

Here's a workflow where you create a *new* branch A, which is based on B, but with modifications:

```
git checkout B          # Go to the tip of branch B.
git checkout -b A       # Create & checkout a new branch here named A.
git rebase -i           # Launch interactive rebase
```

At this point, you'll be brought into an editor with a list of all the commits from the B branch (though we're now in A, a copy of the changes in B). The help text is pretty good, but the short summary is that you can now reorder commits (by reordering their corresponding lines), delete commits (by deleting their corresponding lines), squash commits together (change 'pick' to 'squash'), edit commit messages, and so forth.

For your situation, just delete all lines with commits that you want to throw away, and leave the commits you want to keep. When you're happy with the revised commit sequence, save and exit the file, Git will grind away, and you'll be left with a new branch A that is a modified form of the original branch B.

Git rebase -i is a very habit-forming superpower, but be aware that you should never rebase an existing branch that anyone else has ever seen (or has been pushed upstream). Read up on 'git rebase' when you get the time, as it's a Git skill you'll definitely want in your toolbox.